# My SQL Command takes too long, any simplification?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table (player) of with following columns:

```
playerID varchar(20)
MMR int(10)
RANK int(10)
```

There are 500k~ rows at the moment.

Now I want to update the RANK column of the top 10k players.

So I created the following SQL command

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE player 
SET player.RANK = 10001 
WHERE player.Rank < 10001;

SET @rank := 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpRank AS (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, PlayerID, MMR
   FROM player ORDER BY MMR DESC LIMIT 10000);


UPDATE player, tmpRank 
SET player.RANK = tmprank.rank 
WHERE player.PlayerID = tmprank.PlayerID;

COMMIT;
```

Sadly this command takes about 25 seconds to complete, even with set indices on `PlayerID`, `MMR`, and `Rank`.

Can you help me simplify this command or suggest how to improve this piece of code?

Best Regards

**Edit #1**

Table **player**:

```
Column                      Typ         Null    Standard
-----------------------------------------------------------
PlayerID (Primärschlüssel)  varchar(20) Nein             
Name                        varchar(16) Nein             
Password                    varchar(10) Nein             
MMR                         int(10)     Nein    1500         
RANK                        int(10)     Nein    50001        
Tournaments_won             int(10)     Nein    0        
Avatar                      varchar(255)Nein             
Location                    tinyint(4)  Nein    0        
PlayerLevel                 tinyint(4)  Nein    0        
Experience                  tinyint(4)  Nein    0        
Description                 varchar(255)Nein    Hello People!
```

Indices

```
Schlüsselname   Typ     Unique  Gepackt Spalte      Kardinalität    Kollation   Null    
PRIMARY         BTREE   Ja      Nein    PlayerID    479032          A   Nein    
DeviceID        BTREE   Ja      Nein    DeviceID    479032          A   Nein    
Name            BTREE   Ja      Nein    Name        479032          A   Nein    
MMR             BTREE   Nein    Nein    MMR         9580            A   Nein    
RANK            BTREE   Nein    Nein    RANK        2               A   Nein
```

How this SQL Query "should work":

- "Derank" every player by setting their Rank to the internal Max+1 (only set the players who were ranked before)
- Create a temporary table with the Top 10k players
- Update the player table in comparison with the temp table and change the ranks if necessary

**Edit #2**

```
UPDATE player 
SET player.RANK = 10001 
WHERE player.Rank < 10001;
```

takes about 20 seconds

```
SET @rank := 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpRank AS (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, PlayerID, MMR
   FROM player ORDER BY MMR DESC LIMIT 10000);
```

this Query alone takes <0.5 seconds

```
SET @rank := 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpRank AS (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, PlayerID, MMR
   FROM player ORDER BY MMR DESC LIMIT 10000);


UPDATE player, tmpRank SET player.RANK = tmprank.rank WHERE player.PlayerID = tmprank.PlayerID;
```

These two queries are taking about 20 seconds again.

I want to run them like every 30min or 1hour, but would prefer if they would run a lot faster somehow.

Comment: Why stop at just the top 10k?  Also, I'm not so sure this i doing what you claim it is doing.

Comment: For query optimization advice, we need to see the definition of the table including all columns and all indexes.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff .  This appears to be updating players who are _not_ in the top 10K.

Comment: Assuming the code does what you say it does, an index on MMR would be a good start in trying to optimize since the query is so heavily dependent on it.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers, i edited the entry post

Comment: I'd ask you to execute the statements seperately to figure out if one of those statements consumes a majority of the time or if all three are taking (more or less) equally long. Also how many times do you run that statement? To me it looks like a 'run once to sanitize data' statement but apparently it's not?

From looking at it, I'd say that creating the temporary table is taking the majority of the time needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is necessarily very heavy duty.

Will you be doing this update often?  If so, I contend that is poor design to have a massively updated column in the table.  Instead have it in another ("parallel") table.

Doing so, is likely to speed up the query.  It may even be practical to create a table with id+rank, then `RENAME TABLE` to put it into place.  This would have essentially zero 'downtime'.  Yes, it still takes a long time to compute and build, but the users are not impacted.  I assume that is your real concern.

If possible, compute the value on the fly rather than storing it.  (I doubt if this is practical, since you call it "Rank".)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the best solution. I tried it and it takes less then 3 seconds to create a new table with top 300k players :)